# Callbacks explicacion de como funciona

Tags: javascript, callback

Hola buenas soy nuevo en esto y no tengo del todo claro como funciona este codigo, primero se imprime 'empieza', luego 'acaba' y luego el callback ya que esta en un subproceso asincrono no?  pero no entiendo bien la sintaxis de

```
suma(5,6,function(resultadocb){
    console.log(resultadocb); 
});
```

y porque esta arriba `callback(resultado);`

Alguien podria decirme paso a paso el funcionamiento del codigo porfavor? Gracias

```js
function suma(numero1, numero2, callback){
        var resultado = numero1 + numero2;
        callback(resultado);
}

console.log('empieza'); 

//ESTO ESTA EN UN SUBPROCESO
suma(5,6,function(resultadocb){
    console.log(resultadocb); 
});

console.log('acaba');
```

Answer (score 3):

Los callbacks no son un subproceso, es mas, siquiera se ejecutan asincronamente. La idea de los callbacks es poder ejecutar un algoritmo una vez completada cierta accion.

Los callback son funciones que se envian como parametros y puedes enviar las referencias de las mismas. Esto debido a que las funciones se les trata como objetos o mejor dicho First Class Citizens.

Cuando envias el callback a la funcion sumar:

```
suma(1,2, function(){
 //..
});
```

En realidad estas enviando la referencia de una función anomina, no creando un subproceso. Por lo que esto también es posible:

```
function obtenerResultado(resultadocb)
{
  console.log(resultadocb); 
}

sumar(1,2, obtenerResultado);
```

En este caso, se ejecutara la funcion `obtenerResultado`.

En resumen, la razon por la que te imprime todo en orden es porque los callbacks no son subprocesos ni hilos, son referencias de funciones.

Comment: pense que era al reves, si no tuviese callback esperaria, con callbacks si tarda mucho la ejecucion de un proceso, se ejecuta asincronicamente y por eso puedo pasar a otro proceso antes de haber terminado el que aun no se ha terminado

Comment: cabe destacar ,que puedes reemplazar la función anonima con cualquier función que tu predefinas con anterioridad.

Comment: @Elon.SSH asi es. Lo me mencionas esta en la explicación que di.

Comment: gracias por hacer uso de ese ejemplo.

Comment: @franciscodwq te ayudo la respuesta? Si te ayudo puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

```
function suma(numero1, numero2, callback){
        var resultado = numero1 + numero2;
        /*->*/callback(resultado);
}

console.log('empieza'); 

//ESTO ESTA EN UN SUBPROCESO
suma(5,6,function(resultadocb){
    console.log(resultadocb); 
});

console.log('acaba');
```

/*
Al momento de declarar la función suma recibe 2 valores que serán
sustituidos por el usuario y un tercero que invocará una función anónima al mismo tiempo

Como puedes notar la función suma ejecuta al callback para imprimir la suma de ambos números; sin embargo ese bloque de código no se ejecutará
aún pues la función solo esta declarada pero aún no ha sido invocada

posterior se imprime un mensaje por consola

Ahora si se llama a la función suma y se sustituyen los 3 valores; en este orden:

1.- numero1 = 5
2.- numero2 = 6
3.- callback se sustituye por una función anópnima que recibe a resultadocb, pudiendo ser este cualquier otro valor

Cuando se imprime resultadocb se ejecuta la línea que hace la suma de ambos números y que mas arriba esta señalada por una flecha

Una vez que dicha funciíon se ejecuta y devuelve el resultado se ejecuta el último console.log que dice acaba

POR QUE SE EJECUTA EN ESE ORDEN

> Bueno el console.log de INICIA no depende de nadie por ese aparece
>   primero, aunque la función esta declarada al inicio, se invoca hasta
>   después por eso y el último console.log al no ser dependiente de nadie
>   espera a la lectura en cascada para mostrarse