# Eventos que se autodisparan dependiendo de como se le indique la función

Tags: javascript

No entiendo porque cuando creo un evento este se comporta diferente dependiendo de si pongo la función con parentesis  o sin ellas se autodispara o no.

Me gustaria entenderlo

```
checkboxActivos.onchange = cargaTabla(); // se autodispara

checkboxActivos.onchange = cargaTabla; // funciona como debe ser

function cargaTabla() {
    console.log('entra');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En la primera linea, estas asignado el valor que la funcion `cargarTabla` retorna a la propiedad `checkboxActivos.onchange`. En otras palabras, estas ejecutando la funcion `cargarTabla` y le estas asigando el resultado esa propiedad.

En la segunda, estas asignado la referencia de la funcion al evento, por lo que la funcion se ejecuta cuando el evento se lanza.

Mira el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
var resultado = ejecutar();
console.log(resultado);

var resultado2 = ejecutar;
console.log(resultado2);

console.log( resultado2() );

function ejecutar() {
  return true;
}
```

Como notaras, la primera variable obtiene el resultado de la funcion y se imprime `true`. Mientras que en la variable `resultado2` se imprime la referencia de la funcion y al final se ejecuta esa referencia.

Dale una mirada a la pregunta [Callbacks explicacion de como funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154216/callbacks-explicacion-de-como-funciona) que puede ayudarte